# Jquery event for the function calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator, jeditable

I have this [table](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/QBGG3/) and i can not make working the function calculator in the td.

The script works perfectly but when i edit the number in the cell( just clicking over the cell to get the input number), i do not get the Total Result. Can you explain which event i should apply to my jeditable plugin? Do you know maybe a different or better method to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `callback` event and assign the proper event handler to calculate the total.
Check this code which works and add more actions if think they are needed.
Your code is very strange for me, but anyway it works.
Function `tally` should be defined outside `onrender`  `$(function(){ ... });` block as a global function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function tally (selector) {
      $(selector).each(function () {
          var total = 0,
          column = $(this).siblings(selector).andSelf().index(this);
          $(this).parents().prevUntil(':has(' + selector + ')').each(function () {
            total += parseFloat($('p#sum:eq(' + column + ')', this).html()) || 0;
          })
          $(this).html(total);
     });
    }

    $(function() {
      tally('p#subtotal');
      tally('p#total');
    });
</script>



<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {
    $('.editable_number').editable(function(value, settings) { return(value); }, {
      type    : 'number',
      style  : "inherit",
      callback: function() {
        tally('p#subtotal');
        tally('p#total');
      }
     }
    );

    $('.editable_textarea').editable(function(value, settings)  { return(value); }, {
     type    : 'textarea',
     width: '200',
     height: '20',
     submit  : 'OK',
     style  : "inherit"
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks reflective , i have tried out and it works exactly as i meant, you hit the spot, i know my code was a bit messy,i need to improve a lot, but with just few rows of code you have explained very well what you have done..thanks again